# Reload SOLR core or update with commit to refresh the replicated index files?

Tags: solr, replication

I replicate index files using rsync. I found out that I have to make following request

`http://server.com:8080/solr4/core-name/update?commit=true`

to make the index/gen version on Slave match the one on Master.
However, it takes quite long to update `commit=true` on Slave. Is there any other approach to make synced index file on Slave available to search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really, really use the [`snap*`-tools](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCollectionDistributionScripts) if you're doing manual replication (instead of the real replication support or SolrCloud), and not do it through rsync yourself. These will make sure the index is replicated when changed, and [will make the index reader reopen the index](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Index+Replication#IndexReplication-IndexReplicationusingsshandrsync) when the files have been sync-ed.

That last part is the reason why the commit is needed: the new files aren't available before the current index reader is closed and exchanged with a new one.

Comment: I wish to but I can't simply upgrade to use SOLR cloud. I've been using 4.1 and manually sharding for a while and I think there is a known bug of 4.1 that made the whole index replicated if the slave node poll the master node. That's why I'm trying to use rsync.

Comment: Standard HTTP Replication does NOT require SolrCloud, and does this a lot easier than doing rsync. snappuller/snapshooter/etc. are built on top of rsync if you really don't want to do http replication (which you should), so use those instead of rsync directly.

Comment: We were using Standard HTTP replication until we recognized that it replicates the WHOLE 500GB INDEX every single time on every single shard and it always failed because it took TOOOOO long. Not mentioning that it caused the disk IO extremely HIGH on the master shards, nothing can search because of that. Regarding the snappuller/snapshooter, I thought those scripts were deprecated?

Comment: Yes, they are deprecated because the HTTP replication is the suggested way. There is nothing stopping you from using them, and I'd suggest doing that instead of doing rsync yourself (as they're built around using rsync). The HTTP replication should only replicate files that have actually changed, but depending on how you're doing commits, mergefactor and optimizes can be every single file.